# Apostrophe at end (or beginning) of word

Tags: asciidoc

How can I get an apostrophe at the beginning or the end of the word? This would be necessary for old-style

> 'Tis

instead of

> It's

Or the apostrophe at the end of a word in plural, like

> arguments'

Of course I could also just type

```
arguments&#8217;
```

but this defeats the purpose of using markdown.

Edit: It does not seem to me that there is a defined inline quotation style with single quote at beginning and end, like

```
'some sort of quotation'
```

so it shouldn't be too much of a stretch?

Comment: In what context? markdown doesn't treat ' as a special character

Comment: @Anthony In the context of normal text inside an AsciiDoc document. I realize it is not treated as a special character at beginning or end of words, but it is treated as an apostrophe in the middle of a word.

Comment: Misinterpreted text formatting:
You can suppress markup expansion by placing a backslash character immediately in front of the element.

Comment: @Anthony No, this is the other way round: I can force a single quote in the middle of the word _not to become an apostrophe_ by escaping it, but not a single quote at beginning or end of word to be an apostrophe.

Comment: Can you escape it like the documentation indicates? `\'tis`?

Comment: @Anthony No, I don't know what point of the documentation you mean but this definitely does not produce an apostrophe at the beginning of the word.

Comment: Nevermind, I thought the issue was that the single quotes were causing the text to be italicized. But I did some deeper digging and found the following:  http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#quotation-marks-and-apostrophes  which says that " An apostrophe directly bounded by two characters is processed during the replacements substitution phase, not the quotes phase. This is why an apostrophe directly followed by white space, such as the possessive plural form, is not curved by default."  You can force a curved apostrophe, but not without bound text.

Comment: @Anthony Thanks. I got to that point too, but I think that asciidoctor is a Ruby re-implementation of asciidoc, so I still had a glimpse of hope. At the end, we can't expect markdown to work perfectly all the time, and I can insert a "literal" apostrophe so I guess I'll have to live with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do is to go ahead and specify the single-right-quote symbol as you have done, but you don't have to use the numeric notation (`&#8217;`). AsciiDoc has a predefined symbol for that (`{rsquo}`), so it's not quite so ugly.

```
.Examples of Single-Apostrophe Notation
[width="50%",cols="",options="header"]
|===
|Use this |To get this
|\'italics' |'italics'
|\'\'single-quoted'' (two single apostrophes each) |''single-quoted''
|it's |it's (automatically formatted)
|its' |its' (ugly)
|'tis |'tis (ugly)
|its'\{empty\} |its'{empty} (still ugly)
|\{empty\}'tis |{empty}'tis (still ugly)
|its\{rsquo\} **{nbsp} <- This is what you want** |its{rsquo}
|\{rsquo\}tis **{nbsp} <- And this** |{rsquo}tis
|===
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really doubt I would have found this in the documentation myself.